# Postman shows "Welcome To Zscaler Directory Authentication" HTML

Tags: postman

I am trying to execute a GET request to REST API and getting an HTML response with the title "Welcome To Zscaler Directory Authentication".

I am using Postman to make the request.
Can someone help me with this problem?